# In Hiveql, SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:126 Invalid table alias or column reference 'timesheet': (possible column names are: author)

Tags: hive, hiveql

My query is following this

```
select drivers.Author 
from timesheet 
join drivers 
on drivers.BibNum = timesheet.BibNum
group by drivers.Author 
order by count(timesheet.BibNum) desc
limit 1;
```

But I got this error,

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]:  Line 1:126 Invalid table alias or column reference 'timesheet': (possible column names are: author)

My table looks like this

Drivers

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
| bibnum          | string          | from deserializer |
| title           | string          | from deserializer |
| author          | string          | from deserializer |
| isbn            | string          | from deserializer |
| publicationyear | string          | from deserializer |
| publisher       | string          | from deserializer |
| subjects        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemtype        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcollection  | string          | from deserializer |
| floatingitem    | string          | from deserializer |
| itemlocation    | string          | from deserializer |
| reportdate      | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcount       | string          | from deserializer |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
```

timesheet

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
| bibnum          | string          | from deserializer |
| itembarcode     | string          | from deserializer |
| itemtype        | string          | from deserializer |
| itemcollection  | string          | from deserializer |
| callnumber      | string          | from deserializer |
| checkoutdatetime | string          | from deserializer |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--+
```

If you know the reason, please enlighten me and thank you for your help.
If you need more information to my schema, let me know.

Comment: i put order by DESC since you want most popular author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two tables by bibnum then group by aurhor name. the most popular author will have most number of readers, so count them in descending order. Limit 1 will get only the first record on top.

EDIT: use HIVE instead of mysql

```
SELECT tab.Author
from (
SELECT t2.Author, 
      count(t1.Bibnum) as cnt
FROM  timesheet t1
INNER JOIN drivers t2 on trim( t1.BibNum) = trim(t2.Bibnum)
WHERE LENGTH(trim(t2.Author)) > 0
GROUP BY t2.Author
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
LIMIT 1) tab;
```

Comment: Sir thanks a lot, I tried this but the result is empty. I don't know why..

Comment: put trim(t1.BibNum) = trim(t2.Bibnum). maybe data has spaces at the end

Comment: try this. if it returns records then it will work. SELECT t2.Author
FROM  timesheet t1
INNER JOIN drivers t2 on trim(t1.BibNum) = trim(t2.Bibnum) LIMIT 5;

Comment: Thank you so much, I am trying to use it.

Comment: if you like my answer, pls upvote and accept it. thanks.

Comment: Omg, there is sitll no output for that even though I put trim.. :(

Comment: How many records you see in this query?  SELECT t1.bibnum, t2.Author FROM timesheet t1 INNER JOIN drivers t2 on trim(t1.BibNum) = trim(t2.Bibnum) LIMIT 5;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168508/discussion-between-anxmous-and-gideok-seong).

Answer (score 1):

The error is with `order by`. Only `select`ed columns can go in there. Change the query to remove `order by`. Or add `count` to `select` and use it for ordering.

```
select drivers.Author,count(timesheet.BibNum) as cnt 
from timesheet 
join drivers on drivers.BibNum = timesheet.BibNum
group by drivers.Author 
order by cnt
```